# Unable to write to a file in the internal storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I know their are many topics related to this and used one of them but it didnt solve my problem.So i am posting this question.I am unable to create a file and write to it my contents.

Here i want to write the sensorModelList to a file named myfile

```
private void showAlertHistory() {
    final List<SensorModel> sensorModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
{
                SensorModel sensorModel = 
childSnapshot.getValue(SensorModel.class);
                sensorModelList.add(sensorModel);
                writeFileOnInternalStorage(HomeActivity.this, "myfile", 
"" + sensorModelList);
            }
            sensorAdapter = new SensorAdapter(HomeActivity.this, 
sensorModelList);
            lvHistory.setAdapter(sensorAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

 databaseReference.child(AppConstant.SENSOR_DATA).
addValueEventListener(postListener);



}
```

My file writer method

```
public void writeFileOnInternalStorage(Context context,String 
FileName,String Body){
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "DCIM");
    if (!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
    }

    try{
        File gpxfile = new File(file,FileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(Body);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am unable to create a file and write to it my contents" -- how are you determining this? You seem to have code for it.

Comment: `if (!file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
    }` Change to`if (!file.exists()){
    if ( !file.mkdir()) { Toast( ... could not create directory ...); return;}
    }`

Comment: I have the code but its not working. I cant find the file anywhere in my device

Comment: `I cant find the file anywhere in my device` Of course not. File explorer apps on your device have to acces to your apps private storage.

Comment: then what should i do bro?

Comment: To prove it's being written, you can either root your device and browse to the file through the shell or a root file explorer app, or you can try to read the file back in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"/yourpathhere/");
```

files will be created in "/data/data/app.package/files/...". But you can see them only if device was rooted

Comment: But how do I save a file which can be accessible by all apps without the device being rooted

Comment: Application should store data in its own internal storage. in asset folder for example

Comment: will i be able to see it in my device?

Comment: Yes for sure ! you will be able to